# Плавная смена изображений  в модальном окне

Tags: jquery, javascript

Хочу сделать эффект плавного появления картинок в модальном окне по клику на кнопки prev и next. Использую такой скрипт

```
$('.next').click(function(){    
    clicked.find('img').fadeOut().end().next().find('img').trigger('click');    
});
```

Он работает как-то странно. Кнопка переключения работает, но затухает текущая картинка, не в модальном окне, а в самой галерее! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: потому что нужно выбрать текущую картинку и над ней шаманить. Что такое clicked ? Пропишите правильную выборку, типа $('.modal img')...
Храните какой-то массив с изображениям и текущий индекс выбранной картинки. При клике Next подгружайте pos + 1. При Prev: pos - 1. Если дошли до последнего элемента, то следующим будет нулевой. Если находитесь на первом и нажимаете назад - подгружайте последний элемент массива изображений images[images.length - 1]

Comment: clicked - это переменная, куда сохранена информация о текущей картинке. Модальное окно самое простое:

$(".gallery li").click(function() {
     $(".modal-content, #modal-background").fadeIn();
     $('.modal-content img').attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
     clicked = $(this);
}); 

    $("#modal-background, .modal-close").click(function() {
    $(".modal-content, #modal-background").fadeOut();
});

Кнопка переключения работает. 
Код кнопки:
$('.next').click(function(){    
    сlicked.next().find('img').trigger('click');    
});

Comment: Так модальное окно работает и кнопка переключения переходит к следующей картинке, все как положено. Мне нужно только, чтобы картинка появлялась плавно, текущая затухала, следующая, наоборот, проявлялась. Если не трудно, расскажите про коррекцию подробнее, я только начинаю в jq и комментарий пока не очень поняла)

Comment: @Olga Moscow сделайте пример на jsfiddle, а вот я давным-давно делал альтернативный интерфейс галереи. http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/LZ7Eq/

Comment: Eicto, большое спасибо за ссылку. Я ее внимательно изучила и прояснила один непонятный для меня раньше вопрос, но текущий пока остался. Сделала пример на jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ETJB9/4/
Догадываюсь, чтобы сделать плавное затухание картинок в модальном окне при переключении кнопок нужно написать функцию обратного вызова, куда прописать вызов следующей картинки. И обе картинки (текущую и следующую) нужно развести по слоям, иначе они не будут просвечивать друг через друга. Не знаю, правильная ли это догадка и как это сделать на практике.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ETJB9/14/

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, нужно сохранить ссылку на картинку, которая показывается в данный момент.

```
curImg = $('.modal-content img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
```

Далее в обработчиках кнопок использовать [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete) на этой картинке, передав коллбэком функцию, в которой переключать на новую картинку и делать обратно `fadeIn`, например так:

```
curImg.fadeOut(function() {
  imageClicked.next().find('img').trigger('click');
  curImg.fadeIn();
});
```

Отредактированный jsfiddle

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var imageClicked,
    curImg;

  $(".gallery li").click(function() {

    $(".modal-content").fadeIn();

    curImg = $('.modal-content img').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));

    imageClicked = $(this);

  });

  $(".modal-close").click(function() {

    $(".modal-content").fadeOut();


  });

  $('.btnModal-right').click(function() {

    curImg.fadeOut(function() {
      imageClicked.next().find('img').trigger('click');
      curImg.fadeIn();
    });



  });

  $('.btnModal-left').click(function() {
    curImg.fadeOut(function() {
      imageClicked.prev().find('img').trigger('click');
      curImg.fadeIn();
    });

  });



});
```

```css
ul.gallery {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.gallery li img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
}
.modal-content {
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 350px;
  width: 500px;
}
.btnModal-left,
.btnModal-right {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.modal-content img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 350px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">


  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-close">Close</div>



    <div class="btnModal-left">Prev</div>
    <!--end btnLeft-->
    <div class="btnModal-right">Next</div>
    <!--end btnRight-->

    <img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/5d7b5eedccc289bd332af80a1ad5a226/montero-2017-us.jpg">
    <br>
  </div>



</div>
<!--.modal-content-->


<ul class="gallery">

  <li>
    <img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/a1289c4c6916baabb98e4673c7052f8/2014-hyundai-veloster-reflex-chicago.jpg">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/a039929c8405451173090144693c1fa0/vw-grc-beetle-chicago.jpg">
  </li>

  <li>
    <img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dims-shared/dims3/GLOB/crop/1280x850+0+0/resize/628x417!/format/jpg/quality/85/http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/1799bb1e072b82bda13c81563bdf5d0f/01-lingenfelter-reaper-chicago-1.jpg">
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за ответы. И особенно, zb! Хотя задача была решена через пару дней после публикации вопроса, он остался незакрытым. Хотелось бы попросить  zb (поскольку именно он дал jsfiddle c реализацией нужного эффекта)  трансформировать комментарий в вопрос, чтобы я могла отметить его как правильный.